# ABAC implementation for knowledge graph

Tags: graphdb

Are there any solutions/products offering ABAC access control for knowledge graphs ?

Ontotext has mentioned that they supports ABAC in the below link-

https://www.ontotext.com/company/news/ontotext-platform-3-2-better-system-integration-and-kg-access-and-integrity/.

But i couldn't find any details in the documentation . Is there any way we could try out the ABAC capability in the ontotext ?

Answer (score 0):

There are few examples and documentation about the functionality, [here](http://platform.ontotext.com/soml/rbac.html).

Also there is a working [tutorial](http://platform.ontotext.com/tutorials/rbac-tutorial.html) based on or similar to [SWAPI](https://swapi.dev/documentation) dataset.

Basically the functionality is provided by the `Ontotext Platform`, which sits on top of `GraphDB` instance, where the actual data is stored.
The Platform provides an [GraphQl](https://graphql.org/), which is more easy to learn and use, if you are not familiar with `SPARQL`. In order to map the `RDF` to `GraphQl`, the Platform uses model language called `Semantic Objects Modeling Language (SOML)`, where you can describe the permission model and the roles that you will need.

However, if you want to get you hands dirty with your own data, you'll need to request a [trial license](https://www.ontotext.com/products/ontotext-platform/download/).